Android 12 installed APK，show：E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
My platform is Android 12. I installed the APK file in the USB flash drive through the file manager and found an error.,Need help analyzing what causes this problem?
The following is the error message when clicking on the APK installation
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallStart}: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10027 does not have permission to content://com.huanglong.explorer.fileprovider/root/netflix-mobile.apk

BaseFileActivity.java
    private void openOthers(FileInfo fileInfo) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String type = fileInfo.getMimeTypes();
        if (TextUtils.equals(type, APK_MIMETYPE)) {
            intent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION_PACKAGE);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE_KEY, EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE_VALUE);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY_APK,
                            new File(fileInfo.getPath())), APK_MIMETYPE);
            openIntent(intent);
        } else if (fileInfo.getPath().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains(".bdmv")) {
            if (mIsSupportBD) {
                launchBDPlayer(fileInfo.getPath());
            }
        } else {
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_TAG_SORT_COUNT, Config.getInstance().getFileSortType());
            intent.setDataAndType(transformUri(fileInfo.getPath()), type);
            openIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void openIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(BaseFileActivity.this, getString(R.string.no_file_support), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LogTool.singleton().debug("not find activity to open this type : " + intent.getType());
        }
    }

AndroidManifest.xml
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.huanglong.explorer.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

file_paths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<!--    sdcard目录-->
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="/storage/sda1/" />

<!--    lan挂载目录 / 外置存储-->
    <root-path
        name="root"
        path="/storage/sda1/" />
</paths>


